# How to use a different code style for a module in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

I have a project I'm editing in IntelliJ IDEA. In this project, I'm using a third-party open-source library. Because I want to edit the library and my code in concert, I've imported the library source (an Eclipse project) as a module in my project.

The library uses a different indentation style from my code: I'm using the default four spaces, and the library is using tabs. How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA to use different code style settings in this library's files?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible right now, [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69685).

Note that it's planned for IDEA 13 that will be released in Q4 2013.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder, Thanks for explaining. I've tried-out ideaIU-132.325.dmg, but I haven't found the feature. Is it there in that version already?

Comment: @karolrvn It's not implemented yet.

Comment: Does this feature mean "use a custom 'code style' config file rather than IntelliJ's defaults?" Example- in IntelliJ 13, can I use this Google Java Code Style - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/intellij-java-google-style.xml?

Comment: Note that the feature that CrazyCoder is referring to still has lots of work needing to be done on it for it to be useful for all file types.  For example, it does not work well for SQL files. To have this issue fixed/updated by the JetBrains team, please vote for the following two bugs that were filed regarding this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227665 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243620